# Get the author of the latest revision

Tags: posts, loop, author, revisions

I would like to display the author (username) of the **latest revision** of a post from inside the loop.

I tried `get_the_author()`, which echoes the username and `$post->post_author()`, which returns the user_id, but both return the original post author and not the latest *revisor*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `the_modified_author()` or `get_the_modified_author()`, this should give you the display name of the last user that modified the post.