# How to add editor's name to entry meta byline?

Tags: posts, author, editor, post-editor

I have one multi-authored blog site and a few editors.

What I want is to display the name of the editor along with the author's name in a post, so that it would read like: Posted by , Edited by

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you post the sample code, working or not, that you tried already? Do that is a good practice in this site to make your question avoid "Do-the-job-for-me" format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small screenshot of what this code produces:

[image]

Demo Editor is a new user i added with Editor status and then logged in as Demo Editor and modified a post to test this solution works.

You can create a custom template tag in your child theme like this and add the template tag in your content.php file.

All depends on your theme.

Tested and works on Twenty Fourteen:

Here's the template tag example you can add to a file named template-tags.php in your child theme:

```
<?php if ( ! function_exists( 'edited_by' ) ) :

function edited_by() { 

printf( '<span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" rel="author">%5$s</a></span></span>',
    esc_url( get_permalink() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'editor' ) ) ),
    get_the_modified_author()
);
}
endif;
```

**The above code needs some work however it does work on the front end.**

The editor author link will need to be fixed and you will need to add the text **Edited by:**

Below is an example of how it looks in the content.php file i copied over to the child theme.

```
<div class="entry-meta">
<?php
if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
twentyfourteen_posted_on();
edited_by(); ?>
```

I also added this in functions below to include the new file.

```
// Custom template tags for this theme.
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `the_modified_author()` or `get_the_modified_author()`, this should give you the display name of the last user that modified the post.

From: [other post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69289/get-the-author-of-the-latest-revision)

Comment: Thanks for this @pascalvgemert, i included it in my answer.

Comment: Nice, don't forgot to vote up for me ;)